# filled \diamondsuit and \heartsuit

Tags: symbols

`\clubsuit`, `\diamondsuit` and the like produce the familiar card suit symbols; however, the diamond and heart suits are empty (only outlined), while clubs and spades are filled. Is there a way to obtain the filled versions of `\diamondsuit` and `\heartsuit` in TeX?

A "clean" solution would be preferred, but even an ugly "take this shape and fill it" TikZ hack would do the job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\usepackage{fdsymbol}

\clubsuit
\vardiamondsuit
\spadesuit
\varheartsuit
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please make your answer compilable, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Could you add also some explanations why it works?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It might be a nice touch to say a few more words ... although I admit that the answer is fairly clear as it is already. But you should definitely mention that the commands need math mode and thus can not be used in normal text as shown.

Comment: Can you make with no fill?

Comment: Using fdssymbol package makes some other symbols weird-looking, including \sum and \int.

Answer (score 45):

As Alan has pointed out, the symbols are available in `arev`, which does normally change all your fonts. The following (added to your preamble) only takes the two symbols you want from `arev`.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{87}
```

Unfortunately the style differs slightly from the default symbols:

```
$\heartsuit\varheart\diamondsuit\vardiamond\clubsuit\spadesuit$
```

[image: example]

Comment: The other two suits are 84 and 85.
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varclub}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{84}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varspade}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{85}
Strangely, 3 are filled and 1 isn't (spades)...

Comment: @Caramdir: Can symbols from Computer/Latin Modern be imported in a similar fashion?  I ask because Neo Euler lacks all of the card suit symbols, and it would be nice to import the club and diamond from Computer/Latin Modern.

Comment: @emacsomancer I suppose. Please ask a separate question.

Comment: \DeclareMathSymbol{\varspade}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{81} gives filled spades.

Answer (score 15):

The `arev` package provides `\varheart` and `\vardiamond` which are filled. (The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols Guide is your friend here.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arev}
\begin{document}
$\heartsuit\varheart\diamondsuit\vardiamond\clubsuit\spadesuit$
\end{document}
```

[image: arev font output]

Since `arev` changes the math font, it's maybe not the best solution. (But see Caramdir's answer for a way around that.)

The `txfonts` packages also provides `\varheartsuit` and `\vardiamondsuit`, but again changes the math font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\heartsuit\varheartsuit\diamondsuit\vardiamondsuit\clubsuit\spadesuit$
\end{document}
```

[image: txfonts output]

Alternatively, if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, there are many fonts that contain these characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\suitfont{Dejavu Sans}

\begin{document}
{\suitfont♠︎♣︎♥︎♦︎♤♧♡♢}
\end{document}
```

[image: XeTeX output]

Comment: The `arev` package does change the whole math font though.

Comment: Also possible are `\varheartsuit` and `\Diamondblack` from the `txfonts` package, and these work without extra dependencies (`txfonts` package excluded. `arev` pulled two or three additional packages on my system). Maybe you'd like to edit your answer to include these? It feels wrong for me to post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Martin and Caramdir.  Thanks. I've edited my answer.

Comment: can u provide detail tex file for reference

Comment: @larrycai I've added example documents for each method.

Answer (score 8):

Another font that provides the filled diamond and heart suit symbols is `kpfonts`. From the preamble of my template file for type-setting bridge stuff:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand*\Hs[1]{\ensuremath{{\color{blue} #1}{\color{red}\varheartsuit}}}
\newcommand*\Ss[1]{\ensuremath{{\color{blue} #1}{\color{black}\spadesuit}}}
\newcommand*\Ds[1]{\ensuremath{{\color{blue} #1}{\color{red}\vardiamondsuit}}}
\newcommand*\Cs[1]{\ensuremath{{\color{blue} #1}{\color{black}\clubsuit}}}
\newcommand*\NT[1]{{\color{blue} #1}{\color{black}\textsc{nt}}}
```

of course, this predicates on your willing to switch to a whole new font, so is in some sense inferior to the solutions already given.

Comment: Is it possible to only use these symbols from your font package without changing fonts?

Comment: A variant of Caramdir's answer should work. You will have to go through the `kpfonts.sty` to find the font name (I think replacing the `zavm` with `jkpss` should work), and also find the correct numbers for the symbols somehow. You may want to ask a new questions so someone more familiar with how this works can give you a better answer.

Comment: Here it is: `\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{jkpsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varclubsuit}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{112}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamondsuit}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{113}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheartsuit}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{114}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varspadesuit}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{115}` Diamonds and hearts are filled, clubs and spades are outlined.

Answer (score 7):

The symbols are available in the pifont package using

```
\usepackage{pifont}
```

in your preamble and

```
\ding{168}              % club
{\color{red}\ding{169}} % diamond
{\color{red}\ding{170}} % heart
\ding{171}              % spade
```

to access the different symbols.

Answer (score 5):

I found an unexpectedly easy way here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124347/80217.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ascii}

\begin{document}
\ETX
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You asked this question in 2011.  As of 2020, the modern toolchain with `unicode-math` also supports `\varheartsuit` and `\vardiamondsuit`.

If your Unicode text font contains the symbols ♥ (U+2665) and ♦ (U+2666), you can load `fontspec` and enter them directly, or as as `^^^^2665` and `^^^^2666`.

If you want to use them in text mode and your main font does not contain them, you could patch them in as follows:

```
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Serif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\DeclareRobustCommand\textheart{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2665}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\textdiamond{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2666}}}
```

Another option would be to set a font for that entire block of symbols using `ucharclasses`.

Comment: Thanks; great to know Latex is getting better with time thanks to the work of many people. (By the way, quick question: does your snippet work in Pdflatex, or only in Xelatex?)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, but not PDFLaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

The package `amssymb` provides the filled lozenge symbol `\blacklozenge` similar to the filled diamond.