# Using the alt+number symbols in windows

Tags: symbols, windows, winedt

I recently discovered at that one can make many symbols by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>num pad</kbd>. I then tried to insert these symbols into my latex file, and it compiled, but just seemed to insert a space there.

The symbols I am talking about are: `☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○` (Alt + 1-9).

They show up in my editor (winEdt 8).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
☺☻♥♣♠•○
\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAIK, they are control (non-printable) characters. See Unicode tables [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) or [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character)

Comment: @karlkoeller those are the ascii chars 1-9. These are other characters. The heart for example is U+2665.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Symbols can be looked up in ["The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf):

> [image: ascii]

### UTF-8 as input encoding

If UTF-8 is used as input encoding, then the symbols can be defined using packages `ascii` for the symbols and `newunicodechar` for an easier interface of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ascii}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{☺}{\SOH}
\newunicodechar{☻}{\STX}
\newunicodechar{♥}{\ETX}
\newunicodechar{♣}{\ENQ}
\newunicodechar{♠}{\ACK}
\newunicodechar{•}{\BEL}
\newunicodechar{○}{\HT}

\begin{document}
☺☻♥♣♠•○
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The symbol `•` is already defined with `\textbullet`. Therefore `\newunicodechar` generates a warning, when replacing it with `\BEL`:

  ```
  Package newunicodechar Warning: Redefining Unicode character on input line 11.
  ```

### 8-bit encodings

Some of the control character slots are covered by package `inputenc`. Others cannot be used, because line ends control characters are needed for line ends, for example.

However, if an 8-bit encoding is used with package `inputenc`, then usually the control characters are not assigned. With package `ascii` for the symbols it can be done the following way. To avoid trouble with copy and paste from the web page, I have used the ASCII replacement notation with `^^` after `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ascii}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
% \NUL
\DeclareInputText{1}{\SOH}% ^^A
\DeclareInputText{2}{\STX}% ^^B
\DeclareInputText{3}{\ETX}% ^^C
\DeclareInputText{4}{\EOT}% ^^D
\DeclareInputText{5}{\ENQ}% ^^E
\DeclareInputText{6}{\ACK}% ^^F
\DeclareInputText{7}{\BEL}% ^^G
\DeclareInputText{8}{\BS}% ^^H
% \HT
% \LF
\DeclareInputText{11}{\VT}% ^^K
% \FF
% \CR
\DeclareInputText{14}{\SO}% ^^N
\DeclareInputText{15}{\SI}% ^^O
\DeclareInputText{16}{\DLE}% ^^P
\DeclareInputText{17}{\DCa}% ^^Q
\DeclareInputText{18}{\DCb}% ^^R
\DeclareInputText{19}{\DCc}% ^^S
\DeclareInputText{20}{\DCd}% ^^T
\DeclareInputText{21}{\NAK}% ^^U
\DeclareInputText{22}{\SYN}% ^^V
\DeclareInputText{23}{\ETB}% ^^W
\DeclareInputText{24}{\CAN}% ^^X
\DeclareInputText{25}{\EM}% ^^Y
\DeclareInputText{26}{\SUB}% ^^Z
\DeclareInputText{27}{\ESC}% ^^[
\DeclareInputText{28}{\FS}% ^^    \DeclareInputText{29}{\GS}% ^^]
\DeclareInputText{30}{\RS}% ^^^ or ^^1e
\DeclareInputText{31}{\US}% ^^_
\DeclareInputText{127}{\DEL}% ^^?

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \NUL^^A^^B^^C^^D^^E^^F^^G\\
  ^^H\HT\LF^^K\FF\CR^^N^^O\\
  ^^P^^Q^^R^^S^^T^^U^^V^^W\\
  ^^X^^Y^^Z^^[^^\^^]^^1e^^_\\
  ^^?
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Why is that the char appear fine in the source file and need to be remapped?

Comment: TeX only see bytes as input. Without further treatment, they are mapped directly to the font slots of the current font. And in the often used font encodings `OT1` or `T1` these slots contain different characters. Package `inputenc` makes the non-printable ASCII characters active and allows a mapping. This is mostly used for 8-bit characters and are loaded via option of pacakage `inputenc` (e.g. `ansinew`).