# Package arev and sansmath

Tags: math-mode, symbols, sans-serif

I would like to use the package `sansmath` and be able at the time to define a new symbol `\varheart`. To define the latter, following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9643/8323), I use the code

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}
```

Unfortunately, as seen in the following minimal example, it does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}

\begin{document}

\sansmath{Is the following a filled heart? $\varheart$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Is there a way to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare the symbol as `\mathord` rather than `\mathalpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathord}{extraup}{86}

\begin{document}

\sansmath{Is the following a filled heart? $\varheart a+b$}

\end{document}
```

[image]