# Use symbols without using the package

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I need to use [symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) `\varheartsuit` and `\vardiamondsuit` in package `fdsymbol` without changing other fonts, so I can't using command `\usepackage{fdsymbol}`.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9643/181032) suggest using `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\DeclareMathSymbol`, but simple replacement doesn't work here.

So how can I do a similar job?

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a short working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{<->FdSymbolA-Book}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{extrasymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamondsuit}{\mathord}{extrasymbols}{182}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheartsuit}{\mathord}{extrasymbols}{184}
\begin{document}
$\vardiamondsuit\varheartsuit$
\end{document}
```

Explanation:

`\vardiamondsuit` is defined as the 182nd character in FdSymbolA-Book.pfb.

`\varheartsuit` is defined as the 184th character in FdSymbolA-Book.pfb.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And could you please explain why we need `\DeclareFontFamily` and `\DeclareFontShape` commands compared to the answer in the link? Besides, how do I know the number of a character in a package quickly?

Comment: In fdsymbol.sty you will find `\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{} \DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@mweight@small
    <7.1-> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@mweight@normal
}{}`. I have simplified this.

Comment: >Besides, how do I know the number of a character in a package quickly? I opened the FdSymbolA-Book.pfb with fontforge.app to find the char codes.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @domperor's answer, for symbols in text mode, the `\usefont` command can be used.

[image: usefont]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{<->FdSymbolA-Book}{}
\newcommand\vardiamondsuit{{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}\char182}}
\newcommand\varheartsuit{{\usefont{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}\char184}}
\begin{document}
x\vardiamondsuit\varheartsuit x
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum:

There are various packages, like `fonttable`, for displaying the contents of a font.

Or you can just `loop` through the <=256 `\char`s of a legacy font (note: some Unicode fonts have thousands of glyphs):

[image: some glyphs]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{<->FdSymbolA-Book}{}

%=============== font table labels
\newcommand\ftlabel[1]{{\usefont{OT1}{lmr}{m}{n}\scriptsize #1}}

%------------------- font table
\newcommand\displayglyphs{%
\count255 = 0
\loop  
\iffontchar\font\number\count255{%*
\ftlabel{[\number\count255 =}\colorbox{yellow!30}{\textcolor{red!70!blue!80}{{\large\char\number\count255}}}\ftlabel{] } %need space for line-breaking
}\fi
\ifnum\count255 < 256
\advance\count255 by 1
\repeat
}

%=====================================
\begin{document}
\usefont{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
\displayglyphs
\end{document}
```